# passing information to django views using redirect

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to pass following information through redirect (note:Username is not the username using Django authentication).

views.py

```
def SUserLoginFormView(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form1=SUserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            UserInfo=form1.save(commit=False)
            return redirect('Display',{'slug':UserInfo.Username})
    else:
        form1=SUserLoginForm()
    return render(request,'FormLoginTemplate.html',{'form1':form1})

def Display(request,slug):
    pass
```

Here is the urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.CreateDiaryUserView,name='CreateDiaryUserView'),
    path('Login',views.SUserLoginFormView,name='SUserLoginFormView'),
    path('<slug:slug>',views.Display,name='Display'),
]
```

But it is not working & showing

```
Reverse for 'Display' with arguments '({'slug': 'zjzcjzbhz'},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

Comment: Note that the Django style would be to use lowercase variable names `display`, `user_info` and `username` for the view function, user and username field. At the moment, `Display` and `UserInfo` look like classes, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Alasdair i will keep it in mind. I am trying to implement CamelCase notation  like that in react native

Answer (score 1):

When you use `redirect`, you should use `**kwargs` for the URL kwargs that will be passed to `reverse`. Therefore you can do:

```
return redirect('Display', **{'slug':UserInfo.Username})
```

Or simplify it to:

```
return redirect('Display', slug=UserInfo.Username)
```

In the display view you can use `slug` to fetch the object from the database.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def Display(request,slug):
    user = get_object_or_404(UserInfo, Username=slug)
    ...
```

Comment: then how will i retrieve info from url in view?

Comment: You have `slug` in the view so you can use that to refetch the object from the db.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send in `slug` as an argument rather than as a dictionary.

```
redirect('Display', slug=UserInfo.Username)
```

Comment: Then how will be i retieving info in the function .

Comment: def TargetFunc(request,slug): info=slug

Answer (score -1):

A better method would be to use `django.urls.reverse` like this -

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns += ['hello/', views.view_func, name='xyz']

# views.py
def view_func(request):
    # code
    return reverse('xyz', args=[], kwargs={})
```